# Use of PIT vs TTC PD in a Merton one-factor model

Tags: default-probability, merton-model, basel

Under one-factor Merton framework, like Basel, you use *unconditional* PDs as input of the portfolio model and this "*unconditional*" means it is a *TTC-PD*.
Given a *i-th* borrower, the default threshold is just the inverse cumulative standard normal distribution of the *unconditional* $PD_i$ and you will compare the threshold given by such $PD_i$ with every outcome of the systemic and idiosyncratic component.

Let's imagine to shift the framework: we are now under IFRS9 and for accounting it is requested to use PIT.
How should I deal with *PIT-PD* with a one-factor model? Is it just matter of having different inputs as PDs and define threshold from this new inputs? Or should I consider a particular outcome of the risk-factor that should represent the state of the economy and then evaluate the *PIT-PD* as a PD conditioned to the risk-factor outcome?

$$
PD_i(z) = P(a_i<d_i \mid Z=z) = \dots = \Phi \left( \frac{\phi^{-1}(PD_i)-\sqrt{\rho_i}z}{\sqrt{1-\rho_i}} \right)
$$
given $z$ the the economic state factor outcome.

My idea is to obtain PIT-PD by inverting the Vasicek formula and consider different outcome of the economy (ie. $z$):
$$
PD^{PIT}_i(z) = \Phi \left( \phi^{-1}(PD^{TTC}_i) \sqrt{1-\rho_i} + \sqrt{\rho_i}z\right)
$$

Does this make sense?

Comment: As the 'cycle' component is meant to represent a economy-wide credit(risk) cycle, I would second your idea of adding a (cyclic) systemic factor to your model.

Comment: What doea PIT mean

Comment: PIT = Point-in-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation is already a PIT PD if $\displaystyle PD_{i}$
is substituted by TTC PD.  The challenges of using this model are:

(1) $\displaystyle \rho _{i}$, the asset correlation, is very difficult to estimate.

(2) A multi-period model is required for *z* so that you can use the PIT PDs in IFRS9.

Using Kalman filter and Basel estimates of asset correlations could help you to address the 2 challenges.  For details, please refer to the paper by [Chatterjee](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/ccbs/resources/modelling-credit-risk.pdf?la=en&hash=53B7332226FB2FB1B280B3D643DBB8AFF1FA5F32).

Or you can use a transition matrix / Markov Chain approach that helps you step aside from the Vasicek Model.  For details, please refer to paper by [Varnek and Hampel](https://acta.mendelu.cz/media/pdf/actaun_2017065020759.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is indeed what I was looking for: the Kalman filter.

Comment: For the asset correlation, this paper speaks of a range 12% - 24% in Basel framework for corporate loans. Do you know if it holds for Sovereign?

Comment: @NasserBin I don't know whether it is applicable to sovereign.  Sovereign is tough because data is very limited.  You can dig around Moody's Analytics to see if you can find anything helpful.

Comment: I really don't understand how to apply the Kalman filter for $z$. Should I consider the GDP hts and extract this hidden state $z$ from it? I will open it as a separate question as it actually is another story.